# Python 3.3 Need help on very simple beginners code

Tags: python, file, sequential

I'm trying to read a text file and do 2 thing with evey line:

- Display on my monitor
- Create a backup copy..

A previous code worked but Python displayed garbage on my monitor

Then I tried this code and it's not working complaining of syntax error on the file.close() statement..

================================================

```
file = open ('C:\ASlog.txt', 'r')
output = open('C:\ASlogOUT.txt', 'w')

for line in file:
   print(str(line))
   output.write(line

file.close()
output.close()
```

====================================================

Today is the first time I see Python so please forgive my utmost ignorance about it..
Thanks heaps!!
Cheers!

Comment: Could you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 2):

Your missing a bracket on the line before

```
output.write(line
```

should be

```
output.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to Python, especially with 3.3, you should be using `with` which automatically closes files:

```
with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(fin) # loop only if you need to do something else
```

Which in this case is better written:

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile('input filename', 'output filename')
```

So your complete example would be for displaying to screen and writing line to file:

```
with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        print(line)
        fout.write(line)
```